# Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Если запускать с правами супер пользователя, то программа работает. С правами обычного пользователя вылетает ошибка сегментирования.

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct stlist {
    char *name;
    int dirCount;
    bool operator<(const stlist &rhs) const { return dirCount > rhs.dirCount; }
};

int main() {
    int f = 0, d=0;
    char cwd[1024];
    DIR* dis;
    DIR* inceptionDir;
    struct dirent * dirName;
    //struct dirent * inDirName;
    struct stat fileStat;
    vector <stlist> fileList, dirList;
    fileList.reserve(256);
    dirList.reserve(256);
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    strcat(cwd, "/");
    dis=opendir(cwd);
    if(dis){
        while(dirName=readdir(dis)){
            stat(dirName->d_name, &fileStat);
            if(fileStat.st_mode&S_IFREG) {
                fileList.push_back(stlist());
                fileList[f].name = dirName->d_name;
                fileList[f].dirCount = fileStat.st_size;
                f++;
            }
            else if(fileStat.st_mode&S_IFDIR){
                inceptionDir=opendir(dirName->d_name);
                dirList.push_back(stlist());
                dirList[d].name=dirName->d_name;
                while(readdir(inceptionDir)){
                    dirList[d].dirCount++;
                }
                d++;
            }
        }
        closedir(dis);
    }
    else cout<< "Error:" << endl;
    //sort(dirList.begin(), dirList.end(), [] (stlist const& a, stlist const& b){return a.dirCount > b.dirCount;});
    sort(dirList.begin(), dirList.end());
    for(auto i : dirList) cout << i.name <<" "<< i.dirCount <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
inceptionDir=opendir(dirName->d_name);
```

Нет проверки на открытие каталога. Может быть `NULL` и тогда во  тут может быть ситуация описываемая:

```
while(readdir(inceptionDir))
```

Comment: только что понял. Спасибо.
Вообще глупая ошибка.